# Weird output from hillshade tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, hillshade

I am quite new to working with ArcGIS 10.7.

I have a .grd Raster which I interpolated from some data in Surfer (see first picture below). Cell Size is `1m`, it is projected in `DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_4`, with linear units in meter. In the Layer Properties in ArcGIS it says under Format: GS7BG (I don't know what that is) but I exported it as a .grd raster from Surfer.

When I want to make a hillshade from it, I get a weird output raster (see second image below). How can I get a real hillshade?
I already tried to export the raster as a .asc and .dem file but got the same bad hillshade results.

[image] [image]

Comment: Wat are the dimensions of your grid? (Nr of xcells, nr of ycells, min Z, max Z?) Is it a floating point grid. Which parameters did you use for the hillshade calculation?

Comment: GS7BG = Golden Software Surfer 7 Binary Grid File Format

Comment: It has 5066 columns, 3665 rows, minZ = 580,33, maxZ = 599,97, Pixel Type = double precision for the .grd Raster; floating point for the .asc Raster. For the hillshade calculation I used the standard parameters: Azimuth = 315, Altitute 45°, Z factor = 1

Comment: Did you run the hillshade geoprocessing tool, or are you doing this some other way?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by geoprocessing tool. I am running the ArcToolbox -> Spatial Analyst Tools -> Surface -> Hillshade

Comment: It looks like the coloring of the hillshade is discrete (I count only 6 shades of grey), try continuous greyshading. Has your output hillshade grid also floating point or double precision values?

Comment: The colouring actually is streched, but the pixel value range is small. It ranges from min 177 to max 185, which seems odd. The pixel type is 'unsigned integer'

Comment: Unsigned integer of the hillshade file is the problem. This truncates all the subtleties in the shading, try saving as float, or double precision

Comment: Thank you Hans for your help so far :) But are you sure that the problem is the 'unsigned integer'?. Using the hillshade tool, I can not define the output pixel type. I computed another hillshade from a DEM file I downloaded, and this looks reasonable although it as well has unsigned integer als pixel type. The only difference is, that it has hillshade values ranging from 0 to 254. My hillshade values range only from 177 to  185. Somehow I feel like that this is the problem.

Comment: Well the issue is that your output hillshade only has a very limited output range: (177, 178, 179, 180, 181,182,183,184,185), with only nine values you can't render a shaded landscape. even 8bit (256 values) gives a coarse rendering. I suggest to export your input grid as floating point geotiff and try a hillshade of that. BTW you can render hillshade in ArcMAP without calculating a second grid (layer properties> symbology > stretched, tick use hillshade effect)